# TDBAdvGrid not allowing inplace editing with JOIN Query

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using `TDBAdvGrid` component to display data from database table.
It is showing 4 columns - Group, Short Description, Long Description, Image to DBAdvGrid from table.

```
DBAdvGrid.PageMode = true
```

The option goEditing is set to true in DBAdvGrid.Options.
ReadOnly property of all columns of DBAdvGrid is set to False.

Despite of it, only for the first column(Group) of the DBAdvGrid is allowing inplace editing. All other columns inplace editing is not working.

My SQL query is as follows

```
UniQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select g.name, u.label, u.description, u.image from ugroup g, emp u where u.usergroup_id = g.id';
```

With above query it is displaying result in `TDBAdvGrid` but only first column which shows data from `ugroup` table is being editable while other 3 columns which shows data from `emp` table are not editable despite of setting `GoEditing` property of `TDBAdvGrid` to True.

I am getting all columns at `TDBAdvGrid` editable when selected data from single table.

Comment: What class type is `UniQuery1`? What components/technology are you using? What's the back end database type?

Comment: @Marcus, Backend data components are UniQuery, UniConnection, UniDataSource, SQLiteUniProvider are from Universal Data Access Components (UniDAC) functions similar to the SQLQuery, SQLConnection, DataSource etc..The editing problem at TDBAdvGrid which I am facing is only with join(Advanced) Query where data is selected from 2 tables. If data is selected from only 1 table then all columns are TDBAdvGrid are editable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `TDBAdvGrid`. Editing joined tables via a TDataSet is very (very) tricky. Not all providers support it, and AFAIK every provider (in your case UniDAC) implements it differently. normally when joining tables the "primary" table (which has the PK) is editable via TDataSet. I suggest you contact UniDAC.

Comment: @kobik you are right. I set `updatingtable` property of `UniQuery` to the tablename at which I want to edit data most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in two ways

1) Putting two table (in my case UniTable) components on the form and join them by using `Master Detail Relation`.

2) If one want to do it with `UniQuery` only then by setting `UpdatingTable` property of the `UniQuery` to both tables i.e `TableName1 TableName2` separated by space.